# How to implement a more C++-friendly/OO-capable networked method dispatch mechanism?

Tags: c++, oop, network-programming, distributed, dispatch

Okay question first:
I need to know what alternatives I have to the Incredibly Evil (TM) switch in my remote "object dispatch" (poor man's RPC) MethodCall method.

```
    virtual void methodCall(unsigned int method) {
        bvnet::scoped_lock lock(ctx.getMutex());
        bvnet::value_queue &vqueue=ctx.getSendQueue();
        switch(method) {
        case 0: /* GetType */
            /* emit object type to output queue as string */
            vqueue.push(string(getType()));
            break;
        }
```

Of course one asks what I am trying to accomplish with this method.

I have set up a protocol (network) that implements a lightweight distributed objects system that allows one end or the other to do method calls at one end or the other using object references and method indices each being an integer passed over the network (so cannot use pointers, ptr-to-method, etc).  Furthermore I have a registry map at each that tracks what object references are alive (meaning for what object id integers incoming method calls from the other end are valid).

Arguments are handled with a forth-style stack so you'd have an incoming stream stuff like:

```
3 5 math.plus() 7 math.multiply()
```

to achieve the equivalent of (3+5)*7

the vqueue<>.push() and getarg<>() handle putting vlaues onto the outgoing stream via vqueue and reading arguments via getarg<>() with the <> templated to the supported types going over the wire

This animal is the base class and its purpose is to provide objects registered to a particular connection session (each endpoint has its own registry which is insert to whenever a new object is created to to reference to the remote.

```
/**
** @brief ABC for remotable objects.
**
** Base used for objects exchangeable via object references.
**
** Since secure referencing requires a way to
** track object lifetime a registry reference
** is required for construction.
*/
class object {
protected:
    session &ctx;       /**< @brief for objects to attach to the session's registry */
public:
    /** @brief construction of an object @param sess reference to session to attach */
    object(session &sess) :
        ctx(sess) {
            LOCK_COUT
            cout << "object [" << this << "] ctor" << endl;
            UNLOCK_COUT
            ctx.register_object(this);
        }
    /** @brief base dtor to automatically unregister the object */
    virtual ~object() {
        LOCK_COUT
        cout << "object [" << this << "] dtor" << endl;
        UNLOCK_COUT
        ctx.unregister(this);
    }
    /**
    *   @brief Get object's identity.
    *   @return Object identity string
    *
    *   Overriden by superclass to announce it's identity.
    */
    virtual const char *getType() {return "baseObject";}
    /**
    *   @brief Method call switchboard.
    *
    *   Overidden by superclass to implement methods callable
    *   by the remote.  Currently the superclasses are using
    *   big switchbanks which looks plain evil but at this
    *   point I'm not sure of what to refactor with.
    *
    *   @todo
    *   Base class to implement some sort of glue to take out the switch boilerplate?
    *   @todo
    *   some sort of static enum to get rid of the magic number
    *   method call #s from remote POV?
    *   @todo
    *   automatically declare the methods for method calling
    *   via some sort of macro or metacode?
    *
    */
    virtual void methodCall(unsigned int idx)=0;
};
```

The ugliness lies in the derived objects implementing an actual interface.  It's that switch in MethodCall():

```
class Account : public bvnet::object {
private:
    s64 userId;
public:
    Account(bvnet::session &sess,s64 who)
        : bvnet::object(sess),userId(who) {}
    virtual ~Account() {}
    virtual const char *getType() {return "userAccount";}
    virtual void methodCall(unsigned int method) {
        bvnet::scoped_lock lock(ctx.getMutex());
        bvnet::value_queue &vqueue=ctx.getSendQueue();
        switch(method) {
        case 0: /* GetType */
            /* emit object type to output queue as string */
            vqueue.push(string(getType()));
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

So again the question is if there is another way to achieve the numbered method dispatch on something more friendly to C++ and such shenanigans as some future object deciding he wants to do

```
MyFutureAccount : public Account {...}
```

(and dread the nulcear-fission-angry email I would get from the incensed maintainer that wanted to do this that maxes out the nearby geiger counter...)

It seems like I might need to do some work in bvnet::Object's constructor and set up some form of what C++ does internally (vtable) maybe using an STL map of intMethodId-to-ptrToMember (giving downstreams an easy way to override stuff).  Will the bvnet::Object base class member pointers still work as expected in downstream derived classes however?  Still so many question marks.  Not sure if I'm on the right track or barking up the wrong tree on this potential solution...

Instead of pasting more (I can't predict what else others would want to see I could just point you to the github for the thing since it's LGPL3 open sourced: https://github.com/gau-veldt/Minetest-Blockiverse/tree/master/blockiverse

The most relevant file would be https://github.com/gau-veldt/Minetest-Blockiverse/blob/master/blockiverse/protocol.hpp but take a loot at serverRoot in https://github.com/gau-veldt/Minetest-Blockiverse/blob/master/blockiverse/server.hpp to clearly see how evil the switch method is already becoming in the wild...

Comment: [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: @CaptainObvlious could you elaborate?  I suspect std::map would be the base class wizardry to set up vtables but where does std::function come in?  I imagine the typical use case would be a bvnet::Object-derived object's ctor wanting to write into the base class's vtable to wedge in various method members on the derived class.  Does std::function handle that case? do you mean an animal like: typedef std::map<int,std::function> overworld_vtable;

Comment: I don't want to answer until I know my plan of attack is working but yes it's involving the std::map as me and @CaptainObvlious both mentioned now only I missed that std::function needs the signature it matches as its template parameter (giving the class name when you do member function calls).  As a plus the new pattern also takes some boilerplate out of the old code into a single point and allows a trivial exception to fire for unimplemented methods.  I'm also adding the ability to label the method slots (allowing better debug info).  Now back to mad coding... :P

Answer (score 0):

At least one upvote on the question leads to me to infer that at least one person might be interested in a solution/answer to this question.

I did manage to remove the evil switches and replaced it with what I label as "dispatched method call" or dmc in the code.  They are dispatched as they come in from the network to translate to method calls hence the nomenclature "dispatched method calls"

Now the hierarchy uses pointer-to-memberfunction encased in std::function adapters which are the value types of a std::map:

```
typedef std::function<void(value_queue&)> dmcMethod;
typedef std::map<unsigned int,dmcMethod> call_map;
```

The fun begins in bvnet::object (the base class) where the call map is initialized to refer to the base class dmc_GetType (dmc functor to call the overridable GetType and post the value to outgoing value queue):

```
/**
** @brief ABC for remotable objects.
**
** Base used for objects exchangeable via object references.
**
** Since secure referencing requires a way to
** track object lifetime a registry reference
** is required for construction.
*/
typedef void(bvnet::object::*dmc)(value_queue&);
class object {
private:
    /**
    *   @brief Displateched Method Call
    *
    *   Implements dispatched method call (dmc)
    *
    *   Superclass-installed dmc methods in dmcTable are
    *   callable by the remote.  A superclass sets up his
    *   dmc methods in his ctor by accessing object's dmcTable
    *
    *   As a plus the lock and value queue boilerplate has been
    *   been moved to the base class dispatcher and the dmc methods
    *   will be in locked context and given the value queue as a
    *   parameter.  He also has an exception now to trap calls to
    *   an unimplemented method index.
    *
    *   @todo
    *   some sort of static enum to get rid of the magic number
    *   method call #s from remote POV?  I'll have the ctors store
    *   method labels in the base class dmcName map while it is
    *   setting up the dmc methods.
    *
    *   @todo
    *   automatically declare the methods for method calling
    *   via some sort of macro or metacode?
    *
    */
    friend class session;
    void methodCall(unsigned int idx) {
        bvnet::scoped_lock lock(ctx.getMutex());
        bvnet::value_queue &vqueue=ctx.getSendQueue();
        auto dmcFunc=dmcTable.find(idx);
        if (dmcFunc!=dmcTable.end()) {
            (dmcFunc->second)(this,vqueue);
        } else {
            // called a method that doesn't exist
            throw method_notimpl(getType(),idx);
        }
    }
protected:
    session &ctx;       /**< @brief for objects to attach to the session's registry */
    call_map dmcTable;  /**< @brief method mapper for method call and OO mechanism */
    name_map dmcLabel;  /**< @brief name labels of dmc methods */

    void dmc_GetType(value_queue&); /**< @brief the GetType dispatched method call (dmc) */
private:
    const string methodLabel(const unsigned int idx) {
        const auto &s=dmcLabel.find(idx);
        if (s!=dmcLabel.end()) {
            return s->second;
        }
        return std::to_string(idx);
    }
public:
    /** @brief construction of an object @param sess reference to session to attach */
    object(session &sess) :
        ctx(sess) {
            LOCK_COUT
            cout << "object [" << this << "] ctor" << endl;
            UNLOCK_COUT
            ctx.register_object(this);
            // dmtTable[0] is the GetType method
            dmcTable[0]=&object::dmc_GetType;
            dmcLabel[0]="GetType";
        }
    /** @brief base dtor to automatically unregister the object */
    virtual ~object() {
        LOCK_COUT
        cout << "object [" << this << "] dtor" << endl;
        UNLOCK_COUT
        ctx.unregister(this);
    }
    /**
    *   @brief Get object's identity.
    *   @return Object identity string
    *
    *   Overriden by superclass to announce it's identity.
    */
    virtual const char *getType() {return "baseObject";}
};
```

This is an example of the new serverRoot object once modified to use the dmc mechanism (the monolithic MethodCall and switch madness is gone):

```
class serverRoot : public bvnet::object {
private:
    BigInt cli_pub_mod;
    BigInt cli_pub_exp;
    Key *clientKey;
    bool clientValid;
    string challenge;
    SQLiteDB db;
    unsigned int randbits[8];
protected:
    void dmc_LoginClient(value_queue &vqueue);
    void dmc_AnswerChallenge(value_queue &vqueue);
    void dmc_GetAccount(value_queue &vqueue);
public:
    serverRoot(bvnet::session &sess)
        : bvnet::object(sess) {
        dmcLabel[1]="LoginClient";
        dmcTable[1]=(dmc)&serverRoot::dmc_LoginClient;
        dmcLabel[2]="AnswerChallenge";
        dmcTable[2]=(dmc)&serverRoot::dmc_AnswerChallenge;
        dmcLabel[3]="GetAccount";
        dmcTable[3]=(dmc)&serverRoot::dmc_GetAccount;
        clientValid=false;
        challenge="";
        clientKey=NULL;
    }
    virtual ~serverRoot() {
        if (clientKey!=NULL)
            delete clientKey;
    }

    virtual const char *getType() {return "serverRoot";}

};
```

Important to note here is that there is no longer a MethodCall within serverRoot (or Account or clientRoot and subsequent friends), nor that it has to do anything with dmcLabel[0]/dmcTabel[0] -- it inherits the settings from bvnet::Object's ctor.  By the same token were some futureServerRoot to subclass serverRoot it would inherit the dmc table from both bvnet::Object and serverRoot's ctors.  Thus I now have a proper inheritance mechanism in the dmc hierarchy and no nuclear bomb email from a future maintainer (well not for that reason anyway) attempting to do class futureServerRoot : public serverRoot ;)

All in all a useful refactor.  It eliminated a bunch of boiler plate (that won't be needed on subsequent objects either).  The dmc boilerplate is less bulky in the classes (the implementations may be moved out of the classes inlined or otherwise) and are no longer stuck in a evil monolithic switch from hell.

Not perfect but it is a big imporvement from what I had before, and it provides an answer my original question.